# AppInventor Barcode :: What does "this barcode will only work for pankajupadhyay05" means?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I made a **Hello purr** App in Google AppInventor.

Afterwards i clicked on "Package this App" and under that i clicked "Show the Barcode". A window showing a small scrappy image shows-up. After some googling, i learnt that this is a 2d code for my app URL.

But, What i dont understand is the meaning of line above the barcode image.:

***This barcode will only work for pankajupadhyay05***.

Does this mean, no one else can use this barcode and install the app??

Here is the Image ::

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But it would be useful to show the barcode, or its contents, wouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry mate i thought image wouldn't have been required :P .... I have just uploaded it as you said. Please tell me if u can also install this or only i can ??

Comment: hey buddy, i Signed-in from some other account and checked this Barcode url, it gives 404 error. I guess, it needs my authentication and no one else can use this URL. BTW, how can i generate a Barcode that makes it accessible for everyone and not just for myself.

Comment: You have to upload it to Market. Then see http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents